# Converting numeric data type to a local datetimestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to convert a numeric datatype to a local timestamp in sql?

this my numeric value : 56611838.0

Thanks

Comment: You have to give a hit as to the encoding.  And what database are you using?

Comment: I'm using sql server database. I didn't get the first part

Answer (score 0):

A `timestamp` or `rowversion` in SQL Server is a 64-bit binary field (e.g. binary(8)), but one that cannot be written to.  If you want to compare to a `timestamp` column, use `binary(8)`.

You can convert a `bigint` to a `binary(8)` since both are 64-bit fields and there is an obvious path to the conversion:

```
DECLARE @test bigint;
SELECT @test = 56611838;
SELECT CAST(@test as binary(8))
```

And you could use this `binary(8)` to compare to a timestamp column (e.g. compare if it is greater, less than, or equal); but you can't set a `timestamp` column.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I think I should rephrase my question. Date & time field stored as a numeric datatype. I want to extract that to a "time" and "date" fields

Comment: And what is the source of your numeric value?  What does it represent?  I'm guessing it is some number of units of time since an epoch-- e.g. number of seconds/days/clock ticks since a specific date/time?